# How to set product min quantity against website?

Tags: magento-1.8, product, qty-increment, websites

There are three websites available as `wholesale, retail, staff.` I want to set `min quantity and quantity increments only for wholesale website`. But when I do it through admin panel it applies to all the websites. Since because those attributes are `GLOBAL`.

I checked in eav_attribute table whether there is these attributes. But no luck. Where does these attributes are defined in Magento?

Is it possible to set min qty and min qty increments only for one particular website(e.g. only for wholesale) ?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that out of the box.
The stock management is global. This means that everything that is related to product stocks can be modified for all the websites or none of them.

The min qty and qty increments are related to the product stock...hence it's global.

You can try to use an extension that allows you to manage the stock on the website level. I can't recommend you one but you can try searching the web for 'magento stock management website level' or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Is it possible to override the Mage_core and try to achieve this?

Comment: Found this extension http://instore.gorillagroup.com/magento-extensions/multi-inventory